# PHP XPATH evaluation

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Translation language="en-US">
    <Field Name="SenderName">QueWay</Field>
    <Field Name="PasswordRecovery">Password Recovery</Field>
</Translation>
```

Now i want with php to select the text "QueWay" with xpath. What i have so far so good:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('../xdata/xml/translation/en-US/emails.xml');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("/Translation/Field[@Name = 'SenderName']");

var_dump($hrefs);
```

And what it gives me is an object that i can't echo it ...

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DOMXPath::evaluate()`](http://php.net/manual/domxpath.evaluate.php) returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/class.domnodelist.php).  You can access the element's data like so:

```
$name = $hrefs->item(0)->nodeValue; // QueWay
```

Comment: Ow, thank you, works fine. So DOMNodeList practicaly returns a list/array of what? All ellements, nodes ... ?

Comment: @RowMinds:  `DOMNodeList` is an object which stores `DOMNode`s that can be accessed with the `item()` method.

Answer (score 0):

> Now i want with php to select the text "QueWay" with xpath.

**The XPath expression that when evaluated produces that string is**:

```
string(/*/Field[@Name='SenderName'])
```